# Continuous map on Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $f:U\subset X_1\to X_2$ is a continuous map from an open subset of $X_1$ into a banach space $X_2$, $f$ is not necessarily onto. Is it true that for any open set $O\subset X_2$, $f^{-1}(O)$ is open?

Comment: The usual definition of $f: U \rightarrow X_2$ being continuous is that for $O \subseteq X_2$ open, $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $U$ (hence in $X_1$).

Comment: is it the same as for any sequence $x_n\to x\in U$ we must have $f(x_n)\to f(x)$?

Comment: Yes.  A function $g:A \rightarrow B$ between metric spaces if continuous if and only if the preimage of open sets is open, if and only if whenever $x_n \to x, g(x_n) \to g(x)$